# Macro to Convert Text to Number Producing Inconsistent Results

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in my personal workbook that I use to convert text to numbers due to some issues with how data is loaded into one of our SQL servers. The issue is that it is producing inconsistent results. The code is:

```
Sub ConvertTextToNumber()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim DataRange As Variant
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim lcol As Integer
    Dim MyVar

    DataRange = Range("A1:FZ6000").Formula

    For lrow = 1 To 6000
        For lcol = 1 To 156
        MyVar = DataRange(lrow, lcol)
        If IsNumeric(MyVar) Then
            MyVar = Val(MyVar)
            DataRange(lrow, lcol) = MyVar
        End If
        Next lcol
    Next lrow
    Range("A1:FZ6000").Formula = DataRange

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Most of the time this works; however, I noticed today that a few values that were formatted as text were not converted correctly.

Cell `Q33` had a value of `105,238` and Cell `Q35` had a value of `689,563`. When I run the macro, those two cells are converted to zero. I opened a new workbook to test the issue, put `'128,899` into Cell `A1` in order to format it as text, ran my macro, and it converted to `128`.

I can find no rhyme or reason as to what is causing it given the differences in the values being returned and am hoping that someone either has a better method or has dealt with this before.

Thanks guys for any help you can provide!

Comment: I think Val() would return 0 if the first character in your string is non numeric. Can you verify there isn't a space or some other character in those particular cells?

Comment: @Orilux - it's not entirely that simple.  I avoid `Val` because... `Debug.Print Val("1 E 12th Street")`

Answer (score 1):

`IsNumeric` is basically testing to see if a cast to a `Variant` of a numeric type will succeed. The `Val()` function is combining that with a `String` parser, so it can be expected to exhibit different behavior. So, instead of using `Val()` to convert the string you should be simply casting to an appropriate type:

```
If IsNumeric(MyVar) Then
    'Cast to a number.
    DataRange(lrow, lcol) = CDbl(MyVar)
End If
```

Note that this is a naive implementation - you could conceivably get values that only cast to `Currency` or would be better represented as `Long`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You already know the range `Range("A1:FZ6000")`, I don't know why you are setting `lrow` and `lcol`, also column 156 is column EZ not FZ. That being said you don't have to loop through all the columns, below is a simple way to convert text to numbers.

```
With Range("A1:FZ6000")
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```